# Using sed with ${parameter}

Tags: bash, sed, edit

### Problem

How do we use variables in a `sed` edit string?

### Example

The file `statement.txt` is the sentence

> I like my pet bird.

Given a variable `${myPet}`, how can we use `sed` to replace `bird` with the value in `${myPet}`?

### What doesn't work

`sed -ie 's/bird/${myPet}/g' statement.txt`

The result is

> I like my pet ${myPet}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'` single quotes don't expand value of a shell variable so you need to use `"` double quotes here.

```
myPet="your_value"
sed -ie "s/bird/${myPet}/g" statement.txt
```